# UITableViewCell AutoSizing Issues

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have a UITableViewCell I want to resize to content. Currently, it's cutting off the UILabel with all of the text. Also, it's completely cut off before scroll, and after it results to the below:

How do the constraints/content hugging properties need to change to allow the cell to size properly?

[image]

Ideally, the UILabels should push the size of the cell to be larger.

View controller:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 75.0
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: Try setting `VerticalCompressionResistanceProperty` of the description label to **1000** and `VerticalContentHuggingProperty` to **250**. Same for the `Button`.

Comment: That change had this result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yir5ul0ysqmg4hy/Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20-%20iPhone%20X%20-%202018-03-24%20at%2012.04.27.png?dl=0

Comment: Alright it would be better if you could add constraints to the question for other UI elements also, just like you did for those 2 labels.

Comment: Will update the question.

Comment: Updated with a new image

Answer (score 1):

Ended up writing the constraints programmatically and ditching storyboards all together. Snapkit is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Set the number of lines to 0 for the UILabel. It will allow for the text to appear completely.